# Green Flag in The Great Maze (Super Smash Bros Brawl, SSE)

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

So, as you probably already know, in Super Smash Bros. Brawl, the Subspace Emissary, there is a crown on a level if you have gotten all the gold boxes in a level.

I have double, triple, and quadruple checked against 3 different guides for gold boxes in The Great Maze in SSE. I have gotten all of them. Yet, I still have a green flag in the bottom left corner of the Great Maze. I don't know WHAT I'm missing. Could somebody help me? Thanks!

I have also beaten the game, so I have access to all rooms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orange cubes aren't the only part of whether a level is fully completed. There's also:

- All characters have been unlocked
- All doors have been opened
- All trophies/collectibles out in the open have been collected

I believe you have to complete the level for any of these to count; collecting and quitting won't do anything.

Comment: Great Maze does not have any characters to unlock, does it?

Comment: Also, all doors have been opened, I followed a walkthrough for that, all orange boxes have been collected, and I don’t think there are any characters to unlock. So, the only thing I’m missing is trophies out in the open.

Comment: There was a trophy, not a gold box, that I missed. Thanks for the help!